# many-to-many select_related in django class-based list view

Tags: django, orm

We have an example model:

```
#models.py
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author, blank=True)

    def get_authors(self):
        return self.authors.all().order_by('id').values_list('name')

#views.py
class BooksView(ListView):
    model = Book

    def get_queryset(self):
        q = Book.select_related('authors').all()


#template
{% for book in books %}

    {{ book.name }} ({%for author in book.get_authors %} {{ author }} {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

When I try to get data from template using get_authors function, I see multiple SQL queries that dramatically reduce performance (SQL works about 5sec). Is it possible to reduce queries? Now I see SQL query for each author in cycle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

M2M uses `prefetch_related` not select_related.
Fix the Model (there are different ways to do what you want to do):

Your Model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author, blank=True)

    def get_authors(self):
        if self.authors:
            return '%s' % " / ".join([author.name for author in self.authors.all()])
```

Fix your view:

```
class BooksView(ListView):
    """
    Note that default Django views use object_list for the context,
    in order to use books, you need to define context_object_name.
    """
    context_object_name = "books"
    """
    You don't need to override the queryset for this kind of operation.
    Just define the queryset attribute of the CBV.
    """
    queryset = Book.objects.prefetch_related('authors')
```

Then in your template:

```
#template
{% for book in books %}

    {{ book.name }} {{ book.get_authors }}

{% endfor %}
```