# How to access ManyToMany Fields in Django If Mediator Class is used in relation?

Tags: python, django

I am beginner for django. I had already tried several times to solve this problem. Please consider my mistake if question is not asked properly.

I don't know where I am going wrong.

models.py

```
class Participant(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)

class Assessment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Seminar(models.Model):
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    time = models.TimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    assessment = models.ManyToManyField(Assessment,blank=True,through='SeminarParticipant')
participant = models.ManyToManyField(Participant,blank=True,through='SeminarParticipant')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class SeminarParticipant(models.Model):
    assessment = models.ForeignKey(Assessment,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seminar = models.ForeignKey(Seminar,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    participant = models.ForeignKey(Participant,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    request_time = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0,validators=[MinValueValidator(0),])
    is_survey_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Already try to figure this out too:

[many-to-many select_related in django class-based list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246120/many-to-many-select-related-in-django-class-based-list-view)

[How to Access Many to many field in class based views in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39012367/how-to-access-many-to-many-field-in-class-based-views-in-django)

views.py

```
class SeminarListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'show_seminar.html'
    model = Seminar
    context_object_name = 'seminar'

    def get_queryset(self): 
        queryset = Seminar.objects.prefetch_related('assessment_set').filter(participant__user=self.request.user).order_by('created')
        return queryset
```

show_seminar.html

```
<div class="row mt-5">
        {% for obj in seminar %}
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="card mt-2">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h4 class="text-center">{{obj.topic}}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body"> 
                        <a href="{%url 'seminar:question' 1 %}"><button>Go For Seminar</button></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">

                    </div>
                </div>      
            </div> 
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div>
        {% for obj in seminar.seminarparticipant_set.all %}
            <p>{{obj}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

I want to display assessment too on html page. But only getting seminar related data. In obj.seminar.seminarparticipant_set.all. I am getting blank.

Please help!!

Comment: Just `seminar.participant.all`

Comment: The modeling with `assessment` looks however quite *strange*.

Comment: Am I making my models correct or not?
Please help me on this...